# KnockoutJS, not showing nested property - with: selecteditem

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

## **What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm trying to created a simple "master-details" (Note the quotation marks!)
Where you select a class from a dropdown and get the people that are in the class.

## **What I expect:**

When selecting a class from the `<select>`, show all person names "connected" to that class

## **What I'm getting:**

The name of the class, even though I'm setting the context of SelectedClass Persons

## **My code**

```
<select data-bind="options: Classes, optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedClass"></select>
<div data-bind="with: SelectedClass">
    <ol data-bind="Persons" id="selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content">
            <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I've created <kbd>**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexintime/5x0ohsc1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding expression is broken: `data-bind="Persons"`, you are missing the [`foreach` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) name...

It should be

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: Persons" id="selectable">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x0ohsc1/).

Comment: >.< - Doh! - can't believe I didn't spot that